# Electric arc from a supercapacitor bank?

Tags: supercapacitor

I have really no idea and this is not a homework!

Given you would work with existing components.

Imagine you would like to build a small electric arc furnace say 1-50g capacity; is it realistic to run it for some seconds with the charge from a supercapacitor bank to completely melt a small piece of rock?

Required energy: 1 megajoule for a kilo of rock, or 1 kJ for a gram (according to J. Lux, a NASA engineer).
http://home.earthlink.net/~jimlux/lava.htm

Now there are supercapacitors of say 1 kF, I've read also about 10 kF but that seems more like experimental (Sunvault Energy Inc.)

If I take a 100F/2.7V supercapacitor and apply

W = ½ QV = ½ CV2

from
https://www.electronics2000.co.uk/calc/capacitor-charge-calculator.php

The outcome is 364J; that is, I could theoretically melt a tiny 0.3g piece of rock with that energy and the rest is scaling and controlling capacitors to discharge as desired to deliver the arc?

Comment: Work out how many joules it will take to melt the rock, add that into your question, and then we can work on the electrical energy storage requirements. You might also explain why you think this is a good idea. What problem does the capacitor solve?

Comment: Calculate the energy needed to heat a 1 gram piece of rock to molten.  Compare to the energy a supercapacitor can hold.

Comment: Good.  [Now calculate the energy in a capacitor.](http://www.calctool.org/MOBILECALC/eng/electronics/capacitor_energy)

Comment: If you notice in the equation for cap energy, the capacitance is linear, but the voltage is a square term. The super capacitors you are working with have a max voltage of 2.7V. Meanwhile a single 15kuF 420V cap charge to 400V stores well over 2kJ.

Comment: You also need to think about how to generate an arc. Is 2.7 volts enough under any circumstances? If not, you'll need a boost converter, or a higher voltage cap.

Comment: @Stiddily for the arc, which supercapacitor configuration appears best to you?

Comment: You don't necessarily need a high voltage for an arc. The only problem with low voltage arcs is that you need to get them started. I recently did a low voltage (48V) spark gap for work, current limited at 25A or so, but I had to physically touch 2 metal bars together and "draw" the arc out. With a giant cap bank you're going to lose most of your energy with the initial short. I had a lot of luck starting the shorts from a decent distance (a little over 1cm) by dropping a gold IC bond wire between the terminals. It would instantly evaporate and an arc would form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The outcome is 364 J; that is, I could theoretically melt a tiny 0.3 g piece of rock with that energy?

It's even worse than that. The voltage on the capacitor will decay as you discharge it giving a peak current on connection to the heater element and then falling off.

More bad news. \$ P = \frac {V^2}{R} \$ so the power will drop off even more dramatically. At 90% voltage the power will have dropped to 81%. At 60% you'll be down to 36% power.

Comment: but using a bank of supercapacitors I could switch that right? I.e. starting with a couple and the keep switching to new fresh capacitors to hold the power.

Comment: Why would you bother?

Comment: @J.Doe If you have a supply that can continuously keep capacitors charged to rotate them, then that means you can just skip the caps and use the supply directly. If you don't have such a supply, but have lots of capacitors, then you might as well just hook them all in parallel and charge/discharge them up simultaneously rather than rotating.